# jQuery countdown 360 stop or destroy

Tags: jquery

I am using a timer to validate selected answers from https://github.com/johnschult/jquery.countdown360

I was searching for a solution to stop or destroy the countdown after the redirection to another page on complete using ajax function which is *valider()*. I tried: $("#countdown").countdown360(){...}.stop(); instead of start in the second page script but the first countdown still running.
the script on the first page is here:

```
var timer = $("#countdown").countdown360({

radius : 60,
seconds : 10,
fontColor : '#FFFFFF',
autostart : false,
onComplete : function(){valider();}
})
timer.start();
```

then the second page script where onComplete can be an empty function I guess:

```
var timer = $("#countdown").countdown360({

radius : 60,
seconds : 10,
fontColor : '#FFFFFF',
autostart : false,
onComplete : function(){valider();}
})
timer.stop();
```

thanks for help

Comment: Do I understand it right that `valider();` loads a new page in your current tab/window?

Comment: @Sigusza Hi, yes you are right this is a function to load a new page in a <div> using ajax.I think I have solved it by just putting  'timer.stop();' in the script of the first page  when click on validate button.

Comment: @Siguza `$('#valider').click(function() { 
    
              valider(); 
              timer.stop();
            });`